# Apple M1 to Linux x86_64: unrecognized command-line option '-m64'

Tags: macos, docker, rust, apple-silicon

I am trying to generate an image for my Rust service from a Mac M1 Silicon to be run on my x86_64 box in a Kubernetes cluster.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM rust:latest AS builder

RUN rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
RUN apt update && apt install -y musl-tools musl-dev
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN yes | apt install gcc-x86-64-linux-gnu

# Create appuser
ENV USER=my-user
ENV UID=10001

RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    "${USER}"


WORKDIR /my-service

COPY ./ .

RUN cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl --release

...
```

But keep getting the following error:

```
#20 45.20 error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1

[...]

#20 45.20   = note: "cc" "-m64" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.55.0-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/self-contained/rcrt1.o"

[...]

#20 45.20   = note: cc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-m64'
```

Comment: Do you have the same problem with a hello-world?
Are you using docker native or through a VM? Seems like a cross-compilation problem

Comment: test putting this (i don't have a m1) before cargo build: 
`ENV RUSTFLAGS='-C linker=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc'`

Comment: That worked @iuridiniz!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think `cargo` is using a wrong linker due not detecting that it is a cross-compilation.

Try to add `ENV RUSTFLAGS='-C linker=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc'` to your Dockerfile:

```
FROM rust:latest AS builder

RUN rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
RUN apt update && apt install -y musl-tools musl-dev
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN yes | apt install gcc-x86-64-linux-gnu

# Create appuser
ENV USER=my-user
ENV UID=10001

RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    "${USER}"


WORKDIR /my-service

COPY ./ .

# set correct linker
ENV RUSTFLAGS='-C linker=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc'

RUN cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl --release
```

Comment: Cross compiling Rust using Docker (general info): https://www.natarajmb.com/2021/02/cross-compiling-rust-using-docker/